# Similar random results for different users

Tags: r, math, statistics

How can different users obtain the same randomly generated matrix with rbinom assigning (0/1) in r?

Here's the applied code

`data <- matrix(rbinom(30*6, 1, prior), 30, 6)`
I've tried `set.seed()` but it just generates similar results for me but different for other users

Comment: Are you just wanting to make the sampling reproducible? if so see `?set.seed`

Comment: I need the generated result to be the same for me and different users

Comment: okay then using `set.seed(..)` before calling the rbinom will do this. (when there are stochastic elements to a script Its good practice to add a set.seed call to the start of the script). Note that you may see differences if you are comparing random numbers between different R versions due to some changes in R 3.6;  see https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/7f6cc784523dfa69087958633f7deb309d9c8718/doc/NEWS.Rd#L150-L161: